# Difference in Assigned and Start value in a Sequence

Tags: sql, db2, sequence

I have created a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ
start with 9000000000
increment by 1
nocycle
nocache;
```

The *assigned* and the *start* values are the same number. Kindly suggest me what could be the reason

please refer to the image for the clear picture.[image: Evidence]

this image details are from SYSSEQUENCES Data dictionary view

Comment: kindly ask me if you need more information. thanks

Comment: Sorry that I edited an existing question. I'm unable to create a new one though i have corrected them multiple times,

Comment: Post your table DDL. Is `id` an `IDENTITY` column? If not, use `insert into table (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() + coalesce((select max(id) from table),0) as id, name from table1)`

Comment: Sorry, you can't just change a question. It invalidates all answers that are already given, and will confuse those who come by later. If you have a question ban, you need to improve bad questions to get enough upvotes to relax the ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the sequence has been altered. E.g.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ AS DECIMAL(31,0) start with 7000000000;
values nextval for CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ;
ALTER SEQUENCE CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ restart with 9000000000;
```

then `SYSCAT.SEQUENCES` would show

```
select NEXTCACHEFIRSTVALUE from syscat.sequences where seqname = 'CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ'"

NEXTCACHEFIRSTVALUE              
---------------------------------
                       7000000000.

  1 record(s) selected.
```

but after another call to  `values nextval for CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ`, the NEXTCACHEFIRSTVALUE will update

```
values nextval for CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ;

1                                
---------------------------------
                      9000000000.

  1 record(s) selected.

select NEXTCACHEFIRSTVALUE from syscat.sequences where seqname = 'CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ'"

NEXTCACHEFIRSTVALUE              
---------------------------------
                       9000000020.

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the create statement happened some time ago as >700,000 numbers have been generated from the sequence. It is possible to restart a sequence from anywhere by issuing an `ALTER SEQUENCE` statement such as:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ RESTART 7000000000
```

You can point it back to the starting value specified in the `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement by using just `RESTART` like this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE CA_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_SEQ RESTART
```

Here is the relavant section of the documentation:

> ```
> >>-ALTER SEQUENCE--sequence-name-------------------------------->
>
>    .-----------------------------------------------.   
>    V  (1)                                          |   
> >----------+-RESTART--+------------------------+-+-+-----------><
>            |          '-WITH--numeric-constant-' |
> ```
>
> **RESTART**
>
> Restarts the sequence. If numeric-constant is not specified, the sequence is restarted at the value specified implicitly or explicitly as the starting value on the CREATE SEQUENCE statement that originally created the sequence.
>
> **WITH numeric-constant**
>
> Restarts the sequence with the specified value. This value can be any positive or negative value that could be assigned to a column of the data type associated with the sequence (SQLSTATE 42815), without nonzero digits existing to the right of the decimal point (SQLSTATE 428FA).